grpcio-tools/grpc_tools.protoc How do i use the custom package path
Hi i have a question on how to use the custom package path when calling grpc_tools.protoc
My project structure is the following
C:\temp\test
    caller.py
    --proto
      --foo.proto
      --bar.proto
    --generated

and here some example protos. The foo.proto importing the bar.proto. All are at the same folder level.
syntax = "proto3";
package mydummy;
import "bar.proto";
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

service FooService{
    rpc Foo(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (FooResponse);
}


message FooResponse {
    oneof result {
        int32 mask = 1;
        FailureMessage failure = 2;
    }
}

syntax = "proto3";
package mydummy;


message FailureMessage {
    string message = 1;
}

When I now generate the *.py with following command and custom package path
-Igenerated=C:\temp\test\proto
python -m grpc_tools.protoc -Igenerated=C:\temp\test\proto --python_out=. --pyi_out=. --grpc_python_out=. C:\temp\test\proto\*.proto
result
bar.proto: File not found.
generated/foo.proto:3:1: Import "bar.proto" was not found or had errors.
generated/foo.proto:13:9: "mydummy.FailureMessage" seems to be defined in "generated/bar.proto", which is not imported by "generated/foo.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.

If I don't use the custom package path I have the issue with the relative imports in the generated files when setting the e.g. python_out to --python_out=./generated
Am I using the package path -I wrong? The official documentation is not so helpful at this point.
Greetings

There are a couple of issues:

package dummy

Though not required, it is good practice to reflect package paths in the folder path of your protobuf sources.
In this case, one (!) of your --proto_path (-I) values will need to reference ${PWD}/proto because that is the root folder containing your protos.
Because your protos are in package dummy, I'd encourage (again not required but good practice), you to relocate them to a sub-folder dummy:
./proto
└── mydummy
    ├── bar.proto
    └── foo.proto

Because you've relocated your protos, you'll need to revise foo.proto's  import for bar.proto:
syntax = "proto3";

package mydummy;

import "mydummy/bar.proto";            // <--- Now includes "package"
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

service FooService{
    rpc Foo(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (FooResponse);
}

message FooResponse {
    oneof result {
        int32 mask = 1;
        FailureMessage failure = 2;
    }
}

For examples of this in practice, se Google's Well-known Types:
Where e.g. google.protobuf.Timestamp is defined in ${PROTO}/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto
/path/to/protoc/include
└── google
    └── protobuf
        ├── ...
        ├── timestamp.proto
        └── ...


--proto_path (-I)

The proto_path flag must be used for each protobuf source path that's imported by your protobuf sources with the exception of the aforementioned Google Well-known Types which are included by default.
This is why you don't need to include ${PROTOC}/include as one of the --proto_path flags but you must include a reference to your proto folder.

generated

The generated folder is an output folder. It doesn't not contain protobuf sources and should not form part of the --proto_path (-I) flag folders.
That said, here's your protoc command:
PROTOPATH="${PWD}/proto"

python \
-m grpc_tools.protoc \
--proto_path=${PROTOPATH} \
--python_out=${PWD}/generated \
--pyi_out=${PWD}/generated \
--grpc_python_out=${PWD}/generated \
${PROTOPATH}/mydummy/*.proto

I've used PROTOPATH in an attempt to clarify how proto_path works.
Every *.proto that you reference must be contained with one of the proto_path values that you reference.
Because your proto_path root is ${PWD}/proto, you must then reference protobuf sources within it by their folder (now equal to package) path, i.e. ${PROTOPATH}/mydummy/*.proto

Visual Studio Code

If you're using Visual Studio Code, there's a protocol buffer plugin: vscode-proto3.
You can configure this plugin to reflect your proto_path's by adding a (workspace-specific) ${PWD}/.vscode/settings.json file. In your case, to reflect your use of the proto folder:
{
    "protoc": {
        "options": [
            "--proto_path=${workspaceFolder}/proto"
        ]
    }
}


Following this example, the generated python files do not include the generated in their import statements, which causes all the imports to fail. Did you actually try to import the generated files and it's working for you?

This is a known problem with Python coded generated by protoc. It occurs when the folder and package paths don't match, you must manually augment the generated code to reflect the module hierarchy. In this case, you can either replace from dummy with from generated.dummy to reflect the correct absolute path. Or you can from . import to make the imports relative.

That should then probably be step #5 in the answer, currently it's a bit misleading. Also very weird by the python protoc people to offer options that they know are useless without manual changes to auto generated code.

Try using the absolute path for generated when passing it to grpcio_tools.protoc.
python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I"C:\temp\test\generated"="C:\temp\test\proto" --python_out=. --pyi_out=. --grpc_python_out=. C:\temp\test\proto\*.proto

That's what works for me. Although generated will also need to be a Python package, with an __init__.py file for the files to be importable, but at least they will be able to find each other now.
